# Is there a way to make a contact page immediately visually arresting?

Tags: contacts, groups, tags, ui

As I mentioned in [my previous question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15226/can-we-add-an-approval-process-queue-to-emails-sent-through-civicrm), I'd like a way to show that a contact page is special immediately upon opening the page. Some sort of flag or label, something like a graphic or colour change that stops people as soon as they open the page.
I understand tags and groups, but they require navigation off the initial view, as well as additional procedures that might be ignored in a rush.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM 4.7.16+ has the ability to color-code tags.  Color-coding a "VIP" tag should give a quick visual indicator that someone is a VIP.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a photo of the contact?  To do this click 'Edit' then you'll see that you can upload an image.  Also, the image can be enlarged by clicking it.

Comment: oh right - and use the same image for the photo for all the people who should be treated cautiously - nice work around

Comment: Thanks Andy. Unfortunately, we're trying to add in as many photos as we can of our supporters. So many people who aren't VIPs have photos, and some VIPs don't. 

I suppose we could upload a large red square or something to all the VIP profiles, but we'd lose the actual image of them. In terms of personalization, it's not worth losing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal I have a sandbox module that provides an easy way to modify contact screens in a couple of ways. If it was extended to have a condition for a contact having a certain field value, belonging to a group or having a tag it would be easy to have a reaction to show a block or modify the css on the page.

[CiviCRM Context module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/lolcode/2447999)